# MySQL replace NULL to some value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have the following stored procedure

```
BEGIN
SELECT kids.*, SUM(point) as `point_sum`
FROM kids
    LEFT JOIN tasks
    ON kids.id = tasks.kid_id
WHERE kids.user_id = IN_user_id
GROUP BY kids.name;
END
```

This statement works fine.

My Question: the `SUM(point)` for new users are typically NULL because there is no submitted value yet to be summed.
What I want is if `SUM(point)` is `NULL` then it should return value like `0` but otherwise it should present the sum. I have looked around and not sure how to fix it, any good ideas?

Comment: Use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` -- `coalesce(sum(point),0)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function:

```
SELECT kids.*, COALESCE(SUM(point), 0) as `point_sum`
FROM kids
    LEFT JOIN tasks
    ON kids.id = tasks.kid_id
WHERE kids.user_id = IN_user_id
GROUP BY kids.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SELECT kids.*, IFNULL(SUM(point), 0) AS point_sum
```

That converts `NULL` to the supplied value, in this case `0`.